# Map disappears when using a user-defined function

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to Js and I have a problem I can't fix. I'm trying to write a function that makes faster the creation of markers on a Google map. The problem is that when I want to call the function either the whole map disappears or if I place the call function elsewhere the map don't disappears but the function does not work. I think my problem is a syntax problem. Here is the code with call function placed in a random place for illustrative purposes:

```
var map;
 function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: {lat: 37.621389, lng: -122.378945},
   zoom: 9
 });

 function addMarker(posx, title) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
   position: posx,
   map: map,
   title: title
 });
 }
}

addMarker ({lat: 37.621389, lng: -122.378945}, {'SFO'});
```

It's my first time asking here so please if I need to provide more information or any other tips regarding asking properly and comply with the standards of SO, let me know.

Comment: Why is `addMarker` defined within `initMap` scope? Could you please create snippet?

Comment: also  `{'SFO'}` should be `'SFO'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem relays in the Maps API asynchronous loading. I am guessing the first error in the console.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addMarker is not defined

Move `addMarker` definition to the global scope and call it inside `iniMap` when you know for sure the map is fully loaded and its instance is defined. Also the second parametr `title` should be a string, not an object.

```
var map;

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: {lat: 37.621389, lng: -122.378945},
     zoom: 9
    });
    // now add the marker.
    addMarker ({lat: 37.621389, lng: -122.378945}, 'SFO');
    //_____________________________________________^___^

}

function addMarker(posx, title) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
     position: posx,
     map: map,
     title: title
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I must read more about scope since it's the first time I hear about it. In the simple Js exercises I had done to learn Js I can't recall anyone or the text talking about the scope. Again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. You need to call the `addMarker` function **after** the map is initialized by `initMap`.  The simplest way to do that is to call it inside the `initMap` function.
2. The second argument to `addMarker` (the marker's title) needs to be a string.

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: 37.621389,
        lng: -122.378945
      },
      zoom: 9
    });

    function addMarker(posx, title) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: posx,
        map: map,
        title: title
      });
    }
    addMarker({lat: 37.621389,lng: -122.378945}, 'SFO');
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```